# How to customize material ui breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, material-design

```
breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1230,
      xl: 1536,
},
I
```

want to add some extra pixel in Large breakpoint

```
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 0,
      sm: 600,
      md: 900,
      lg: 1230,
      xl:1536,
    },
  },
});
```

I have try to override the lg pixel but its not working.

Comment: You tried this? https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/#custom-breakpoints

Comment: Yes, But not work.